# problems with "method" in jquery/javascript module structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having a problem using the "module" pattern in javascript. At the line where i am trying to call a "method" or "private function" of my module, i am getting an syntax error.
seems like my "private function" is not known inside the `ajax`-function. I just know that there's usually no problem calling other functions (of other modules for example) inside the `ajax`-function.

i already tried `SearchContainer._output()`, but then i get the error "Object doesn't support property or method '_output'".

so how do i call my "private function" `_output()` inside the `ajax`-function in this javascript-module?

my code:

```
var SearchContainer = (function(){

    var _php_interface = "interface.php";

    var init = function(){
        _callInterface("init");
    };

    var _callInterface = function(mode, params){
        $.ajax({
            url: _php_interface, 
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                mode: mode,
                params: params
            },
            dataType: "html",
            beforeSend: function(){
            },
            success: function( result ) {
                _output( $.parseJSON( result ) );
            },
            complete: function(){
            }
        });
    };

    var _output = function (obj){
        ....
    };

    return{
        init: init
    };
})();
```

thank you !

Comment: you could try declaring with this._output = function... and then calling with this._output(); maybe because it is inside a anonymous function... for me it would be interessting why are you doing it in a anonymous function

Comment: thanks but your suggestion gets me an "identifier expected"-error. which function do you mean by anonymous function? `_callInterface` for example isn't an anonymous function, i am just following the module design pattern. or are you talking about the ajax function?

Comment: You code looks fine to me. A syntax error is **not** a runtime error, maybe you just forget a bracket or colon somewhere?

Comment: @Halcyon you are right - it doesn't have to do with my `_output` function, the problem seems to be caused by the `$.parseJSON()` function/code. i am still debugging right now.

Comment: yes, it was `$.parseJSON()` giving me the syntax-error because my `JSON` was invalid. but isn't it quite strange that you get just a generic syntax error for that? and how do i handle my question now besides answering it myself?